# Rsyslog Regex and DynaFile template

Tags: rsyslog

I'm using the below template to extract only required fields from the firewall log to save bandwidth and license cost in Splunk. It's working when I save it to the static file but I need file names should be saved in timestamp so that I will rotate the old logs. I'm trying to use DynaFile but I don't know how can I use both templates for a single log?

Working template with static file:

```
template(name="clean" type="string"
         string="%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME%  %msg:R,ERE,0,DFLT:type=\"([^\"]*)\"--end% %msg:R,ERE,0,DFLT:subtype=\"([^\"]*)\"--end% %msg:R,ERE,0,DFLT:level=\"([^\"]*)\"--end% %msg:R,ERE,0,DFLT:eventtime=[1-9]+--end% %msg:R,ERE,0,DFLT:srcip=(.*) srcport=[0-9]+--end% %msg:R,ERE,0,DFLT:srcintf=\"([^\"]*)\"--end%\n"
        )

if $hostname == '192.168.0.1' then action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/firewall.log" template="clean")
```

How can I save this outcome of this template using DynaFile? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [omfile](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules/omfile.html) module accepts the parameter `"dynaFile="` instead of `"file="` to specify a template for a dynamic filename.

If you just use `%timestamp%` in your filename, it will probably create a new file for each message, as the timestamp includes hours, minutes and seconds. One possibility is to convert the timestamp into a standard format called rfc3339, and then just take the year-month-date part of that string, using a [property replacer](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/property_replacer.html).

```
template(name="mydynafile" type="string" string="/var/log/my-%timestamp:1:10:date-rfc3339%.log")

if $hostname == '192.168.0.1' then action(type="omfile" dynaFile="mydynafile" template="clean")
```